# Proof inequality using the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm trying to proof the following inequality: 
$x+1<e^{x}<2x+1$ for $0<x\leq log2$ 
I used the MVT on with $f(t)=e^{t}$ on the interval $(0,x)$ to proof that $x+1<e^{x}$ and I tried to do the same with $(x, log2)$ but I only got to $e^{x}<2x-2log2+2$. 
 Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have shown that $e^x < 2x+2-2\log(2)$ then use $2- 2\log(2) < 1$ to prove the upper limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $g(t)=e^t-(2t+1)$. We see that $g(0)=0$. Assume that there exists $c\in(0,\log 2)$ such that $g(c)=0$. Now, apply Rolle's theorem (which is only a special case of MVT). You should arrive at a contradiction quickly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The left-hand side inequality  is true for all $x$ and results from $\mathrm e^x$ being a `convex`  function.

As to the right-hand side inequality apply it on $[0,x]$: you obtain a $y\in (0,x)$ such that
$\;\mathrm e^x-1=x\mathrm e^y$. Can you bound $\mathrm e^y$ independently of $x$, knowing $x\in (0,\log 2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series at the origin of $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ (which is an entire function) only has positive coefficients, hence it is trivial that $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is both increasing and convex on $[0,\log 2]$. In particular

$$ \forall x\in(0,\log 2),\quad f(0)< f(x) < f(\log 2) $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \forall x\in(0,\log 2),\quad x+1 < e^x < \frac{x}{\log 2}+1. $$
$\frac{1}{\log 2}<2$ is equivalent to $e<4$.